# Adding button sound in Android

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to add button sounds in my android app. They work well in all activities besides ones in which the method OnClick is separated from OnClickListener :

```
package com.example.quizdladzieci;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ActivityChose extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
 public static final String EXTRA_NUMBER = "com.example.application.example.EXTRA_NUMBER";
 private Button buttonAdd;
 private Button buttonMinus;
 private Button buttonMultiple;
 private Button buttonDivide;
 private Button buttonDivide2;
 public int no;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_chose);

     buttonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
     buttonMinus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMinus);
     buttonMultiple = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMultiple);
     buttonDivide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDivide);
     buttonDivide2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDivide2);
     final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sample);

     buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
     buttonMinus.setOnClickListener(this);
     buttonMultiple.setOnClickListener(this);
     buttonDivide.setOnClickListener(this);
     buttonDivide2.setOnClickListener(this);



 }


 public void openActivity() {
     Intent intent;
     if(no == 1 || no == 2){
         intent = new Intent(this, CalculatorActivity.class);
         intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NUMBER, no);
         startActivity(intent);
     } else if(no == 3){
         intent = new Intent(this, ActivityMultiple.class);
         intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NUMBER, no);
         startActivity(intent);
     } else if(no == 4){
         intent = new Intent(this, ActivityDivide.class);
         intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NUMBER, no);
         startActivity(intent);
     } else if(no == 5){
        /* intent = new Intent(this, ActivityDivide2.class);
         startActivity(intent);*/
     }
 }

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
     switch(v.getId()) {
         case R.id.buttonAdd:
             no = 1;
             openActivity();
             break;
         case R.id.buttonMinus:
             no = 2;
             openActivity();
             break;
         case R.id.buttonMultiple:
             no = 3;
             openActivity();
             break;
         case R.id.buttonDivide:
             no = 4;
             openActivity();
             break;
         case R.id.buttonDivide2:
             no = 5;
             openActivity();
             break;
     }
 }
}
```

And here's my mediaPlayer line that I put in OnCreate method:

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sample);
```

to make the button sound working properly I put the line:

```
mp.start();
```

in the OnClick method that is usually placed inside OnClickListener, but it won't work in this specific case as you can see in the first code sample. Can you please tell me how should I reorganise the code without deleting the case method to properly put the mp.start(); so the button sound could work properly? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Make `mp` an instance variable of `ActivityChose` instead of having it as a local variable of `onCreate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 MediaPlayer mp;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sample);
 }
```

put mp.start(); in your onclick() method and make sure the raw folder have the sample file.

Comment: `mp` can't be declared `final` if it's initialized in `onCreate`.

Comment: Hello, when I put mediaplayer declaration in OnCreate method and mp.start(); in OnClick method, mp goes red as it was not initilized.